# $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is homeomorphic to $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, +\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ endowed with the order topology and the line segment $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, +\frac{\pi}{2}]$ with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to prove that $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is homeomorphic to $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, +\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Here is my attempt : I consider the function $\varphi$ on $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, +\frac{\pi}{2}]$ by extending $\tan$ ($\varphi(-\frac{\pi}{2})=-\infty$ and $\varphi(+\frac{\pi}{2})=+\infty$).

It is to see that $\phi$ is bijective since one can introduce $\arctan$ on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ by sending $-\infty$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $+\infty$ to $+\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Could anyone help proving the continuity of $\varphi$ ?

Comment: Is $\bar{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$?

Comment: Yes Arthur. Sorry of the omission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that your function $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, you can use this general theorem: If $X,Y$ are two ordered sets and $\phi : X \to Y$ is an order preserving bijection then $\phi$ is a homeomorphism with respect to the order topologies on $X$ and $Y$.

You can easily apply this theorem by checking that your function $\phi : [-\pi/2,\pi/2] \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is an order preserving bijection.

The proof of the theorem is very simple. Here is a sub-basis for the order topology on $X$, two sub-basis elements associated to each point $x_0 \in X$: 
$$I^+(x_0) = \{x > x_0 \,\bigm|\, x \in X\} \quad\text{and}\quad I_-(x_0) = \{x < x_0 \, \bigm| \, x \in X\}
$$
and similarly two sub-basis elements associated to each $y_0 \in Y$:
$$I^+(y_0) = \{y > y_0 \,\bigm|\, y \in Y\} \quad\text{and}\quad I_-(y_0) = \{y < y_0 \, \bigm| \, y \in Y\}
$$
Since $\phi$ is an order preserving bijection from $X$ to $Y$, clearly $\phi$ induces a bijection between these sub-bases, given by the formulas $\phi(I^+(x_0)) = I^+(\phi(x_0))$ and $\phi(I^-(x_0)) = I^-(\phi(x_0))$. Thus $\phi$ maps every finite intersection of sub-basis elements of $X$ to a finite intersection of sub-basis elements of $Y$, and vice versa for $\phi^{-1}$. And similarly for unions of finite intersections of sub-basis elements. Thus, $\phi$ maps every open subset of $X$ maps to an open subset of $Y$, and $\phi^{-1}$ maps every open subset of $Y$ to an open subset of $X$.

Comment: To Lee Mosher : Thank you so much. Satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that tan is continuous on the open interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Moreover $\lim_{x\to\pm\frac{\pi}{2}}tan(x)=\pm\infty$ because sin(x) remains bounded and cos(x) converges to 0 (and the signs remain constant below and above x=0).

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The function $\phi$ it is a very well known example of homeomorphism of  the open interval $I=]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ on $\mathbb R$ and it is inmediate its continuous extension  to the compactification of $I$ and $\mathbb R$.

Every pair of closed (or open) real segments, both not reduced to a point, they are homeomorphic. The figure shows a clearly continuous bijection  whose analytical expression is not difficult to obtain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for your interest. 

Why it is immediate that the extention is continuous ? That is my issue point ! I am trying to use the caracterization : the inverse image of an open set is open for the extention of $\phi$

Comment: Because the extremes are now (with $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$) elements of the considered segments; your try with inverse image of an open, it is easy since your function is increasing.